# Exporting nodes using Views Bonus Pack strips all formatting

Tags: nodes, migrations, importing-exporting

I've exported all of my nodes using Views Bonus Pack Export CSV; it works rather nicely. The only trouble is that it strips all of the formatting on my nodes: no paragraphs, no bold text, nothing. The resulting node is a single block of text.

Is there any way I can work around this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no - this restriction is by design in the Views Bonus Pack module because of the difficulties in exporting HTML tags in a CSV format but there is a [patch available in this d.o thread](http://drupal.org/node/1064020).